# Save R file to Stata while preserving datetime format

Tags: r, stata

Hi i need with saving file from RDS to Stata.

I have multiple files in .RDS format and i want to save all of them in stata (.dta) format.
i used the write.dta() to save but when i open in stata, i realized that my datetime is wrong and i cannot convert it back

i.e i have a variable called "datetime" in R which shows the date and time in this format (2019-09-13 00:12:00)

i want to be able to get back this datetime when i save the file in stata format.

how should i save the files so that i can preserve the datetime format. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for the `write.dta()`[function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/write.dta.html):

> Unless disabled by argument convert.dates = FALSE, R date and date-time objects (POSIXt classes) are converted into the Stata date format, the number of days since 1960-01-01. (For date-time objects this may lose information.) Stata can be told that these are dates by

```
format xdate %td;
```

> It is possible to pass objects of class POSIXct to Stata to be treated as one of its versions of date-times. Stata uses the number of milliseconds since 1960-01-01, either excluding (format %tc) or counting (format %tC) leap seconds. So either an object of class POSICct can be passed to Stata with convert.dates = FALSE and converted in Stata, or 315619200 should be added and then multiplied by 1000 before passing to write.dta and assigning format %tc. Stata's comments on the first route are at http://www.stata.com/manuals13/ddatetime.pdf, but at the time of writing were wrong: R uses POSIX conventions and hence does not count leap seconds.

Another approach would be to format the date time variable as character before writing to Stata. This can be accomplished as follows:

```
aDateTime <- as.POSIXct("2020-05-28 13:00:00")

aDateTime

> aDateTime
[1] "2020-05-28 13:00:00 EDT"
>
```

Now that we have a date time object, let's convert it to character with the `strftime()` function.

```
# convert to string
strftime(aDateTime,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

...and the output:

```
> # convert to string
> strftime(aDateTime,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2020-05-28 13:00:00"
>
```

Comment: i already did this  
time = strftime(as.POSIXct(log_dt), format="%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC", usetz = "FALSE")
before i save to stata but i still dont get the correct value

Comment: @ruixinlee - are you saying that when you read the data into Stata as a character string, the character strings don't match the character strings in the R data frame, or is there some other type of problem?

Comment: yes if i use %td i can only get back the date not the time

Comment: @ruixinlee - What happens if you pass the character string without formatting it as %tc in R? Does the character representation of the date times in Stata match the character representation in R?

Comment: if its just in R, then its fine, only when to stata then have issue

Comment: @ruixinlee - what happens if you read the data into Stata as a character field, and convert it to date time after loading it into Stata? Does the character field version of the data in Stata match the data in R?

Comment: i fixed the issue. i think there is a need to create a new variable to go about the issue